# why don't police cars have lug nuts?

Tags: tires

[image]

I don't know if it's clear from the picture but the car doesn't have lug nuts on the rim. So how do they replace tires? No doubt the lack of lug nuts is a security consideration to prevent people from taking tires off or whatever but presumably cop cars still need to have their tires replaced from time to time.

Comment: How do you figure it doesn't have lug nuts?  It looks to me like they'd just be under the hubcap.

Answer (score 16):

Yes! They have lug nuts.
There is a center cap which is removed to access the lug nuts.

[image]
Center Cap

[image]
Wheel